# Slick2D Music not working

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I am currently testing Slick2D and thats why i am writing a Pong Game,
Also, in this PongGame you can select Music Files, which are in the ./music Folder

When i run it through Eclipse, all works perfectly.
When i export it, run it with all natives and Librarys in the Folder, it also starts,
but the Music Menu does not work (It just crashes when i select a Music)

The code you can see on:
https://bitbucket.org/JohnnyCrazy/pingpong/src/f2fd635ccfef/src/me/Johnny/Slick2D?at=master

```
Error: Mon Feb 04 13:47:05 CET 2013 ERROR:OpenAL error: Invalid
Operation (40964) org.lwjgl.openal.OpenALException: OpenAL error:
Invalid Operation (40964)
        at org.lwjgl.openal.Util.checkALError(Util.java:64)
        at org.lwjgl.openal.AL10.alDeleteBuffers(AL10.java:1097)
        at org.newdawn.slick.openal.AudioImpl.release(AudioImpl.java:56)
        at org.newdawn.slick.Music.release(Music.java:424)
        at me.Johnny.Slick2D.Slick2D.setMusic(Slick2D.java:57)
        at me.Johnny.Slick2D.MusikState.update(MusikState.java:108)
        at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.update(StateBasedGame.java:278)
        at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:678)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:456)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:361)
        at me.Johnny.Slick2D.Slick2D.main(Slick2D.java:40) Mon Feb 04 13:47:05 CET 2013 ERROR:Game.update() failure - check the game code.
  org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.update() failure - check the
  game code.
         at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:684)
         at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:456)
         at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:361)
         at me.Johnny.Slick2D.Slick2D.main(Slick2D.java:40)
```

I don't understand why it works in Eclipse and exported it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDocs for the constructor of [`Music(String)`](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Music.html#Music%28java.lang.String%29) are not entirely clear on how it interprets the `String`.  J2SE methods that take a `String` typically presume it to represent the path to a `File`.  If that is the case, that is also the reason behind the failure.

Typically those types of resources become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) when the app. is built.  An embedded resource must be accessed by `URL`.  See the [embedded resource info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for tips on forming the `URL`.

Comment: I think thats not the Problem, because when i run my Game with Eclipse, all works fine, i can select Music for playback and i hear it. The only Problem is, when i export it, then the Error appears when i select a Music

Comment: None of your comment adds information that I did not already know and consider.  I suggested to try to & access the sound by URL over 3/4 of an hour ago.  *What happened when you tried it?*

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but embedded-resources are "embedded into the binary of the application itself.", but it shouldnt be like that, the Application should scan the FOlder outside the Jar for music, not inside. I tried it with URL, but it gives me a NullPointer